# How do i calculate the sum of series s = 1=(1! + 2! +3! . . + n!) % 1000000007 with n ranging from 0 to 10^6

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

i need to calculate the sum of this series  s = (1! + 2! +3! . . + n!) % 1000000007 with 0 ≤ n ≤ 1000000.
my current code is:

```
from math import *
n = int(input())
i = 1
s = 0
while i <= n:
    s += factorial(i)
    i += 1
print(s % (10**9 + 7))
```

Comment: Don't even try to calculate the factorials of such big numbers. Use some maths.

Comment: I'd suggest reducing to the mod space more often, as you'll otherwise end up working with numbers occupying all the memory of your computer and beyond. But I agree with @ThierryLathuille; a smarter approach will almost certainly still be needed.

Comment: JIC anyone wonders what's so special about 1,000,000,007 - it's the smallest 10-digit prime.

Comment: Ah, too sad it's a python one. :) But actually this should be manageable in other languages. The trick is using a kind of modded factorial function, multiplying a remainder on the next number instead of the whole result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of the rules of modular arithmetic and of the fact that each factorial in the sum can be derived from the previous one.

You can just keep the sum and previously calculated factorial modulo 10000000007. This way, you never manipulate any large number.

So, you could do:

```
def modded_factorial_sum(n, modulo):
    res = 0
    curr_fact = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        curr_fact *= i
        curr_fact %= modulo

        res += curr_fact
        res %= modulo
        
    return res

modded_factorial_sum(1000000, 1000000007)
# 370927276
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call the factorial function for each function.
According to modular arithmetic,

1. `(a*b)%c = ((a%c)*(b%c))%c`
2. `(a+b)%c = ((a%c)+(b%c))%c`

For each factorial in the sum, you can obtain the value by multiplying the number by the previous factorial `n! = n*(n-1)!` using the above modular multiplication. You can similarly sum up these values to get the answer you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could also compute the sum backwards:

```
def factorial_sum(n):
    res = 1 if n else 0
    while n > 1:
        res = (res * n + 1) % (10**9 + 7)
        n -= 1
    return res
```

Demo:

```
>>> factorial_sum(10**6)
370927276
```

How I got that, example for n=6:

```
  1! + 2! + 3! + 4! + 5! + 6!
= 1! + 2! + 3! + 4! + 5! + 6*5!
= 1! + 2! + 3! + 4! + 7*5!
= 1! + 2! + 3! + 4! + 7*(5*4!)
= 1! + 2! + 3! + 4! + 35*4!
= 1! + 2! + 3! + 36*4!
= ...
```

Comment: Nice: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227551/sum-k-1-2-3-cdots-n-is-there-a-generic-formula-for-this/242413#comment7819144_227551